# Calling Java RESTful webservice in Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest

i have created a **Java Restful Web service**. Now i want to access it in **Android**. There are different methods in Webservice. Web service is running on **http://192.15.10.62:8080**.
how should i call a method named **getGreetingMsg()** in webservice which take a string argument and return a simple String message.

**Web service Details**

Project name **RestFulWS**

package Name **rest.ws.server**

class Name   **helloAndroid**

Method Name  **getGreetingMsg(string argument)**

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: this is not RESTful service ...

Comment: @Selvin why whats wrong with this

Comment: RESTful services dont have methods .... This services using http methods

Comment: here is my method     @GET
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
 public String getGreetingMsg(String mesg) 
 {
  return "Hello User";
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depend on the Web server you are using because each type of server will have its own URL to service hosted on it. If you are using JBOSS server then your URL looks like this
IP:PORT/projectname/webservicename/method name

Answer (score 5):

Simply with an HTTP client like [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html).

**EDIT:** RESTful web service is accessible through URL like:

```
http://yourserver/someservice/<categoryID>/<objectID>
```

So, you can test your webservice from a web browser like Internet Explorer or Mozilla Firefox.

Then, on Android, use HTTP Get request and the AndroidHttpClient.

Don't forget to set the INTERNET permission in your AndroidManifest.xml too

Comment: can u tell me what is categoryID and ObjectID

Comment: It's just a general example. <categoryID> and <objectID> are variables. In your case, the URL could be something like: http://yourserver/helloAndroid/getGreetingMsg/<argument>

Comment: i am accessing a webservice by http://10.99.17.103:8081/hello/sayPlainTextHello/my_string_argument                                                                           HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); ---------                                            
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url); ----------                                                         
**response = httpclient.execute(httpget);** -------- but i am getting error at this Last line... Exception is Target Host must not be Null

Comment: Are you testing on a phone or emulator? Besides, have you tried to access this URL from the web browser?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're not sure how to approach your own API.  If your API supports GET, then open a web browser and try some GET commands.  Once you have a GET statement working, work through this tutorial: http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-login-screen-using-httpclient.html.

Once you're set with POST, turn off GET in your webserver.

Good luck!

db